# How to populate filter results in a different worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I set up a data to filter by different categories in a drop down list.

The data is on one sheet, and when filters are selected, the results are generated on that same sheet (exactly how a filter would typically work in Excel).

I want that the database is held on a different worksheet, while the filters/drop down menus and results are in another. This is to hide the database with everyone's information, and only populate the results for the filters that were selected.

**The autofilter code:**

```
Sub AdvFilt()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B13", Range("U") & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  rng.AdvancedFilter 1, [X1:AE2], 0
End Sub
```

Is it possible to designate a range from a different worksheet?

Comment: Yes, it's very possible. You can trigger a worksheet_change macro to fire when the drop down is changed to filter you data base, copy the visible rows (including header) to a new sheet. How to do all of this is well documented on this site

Answer (score 0):

If that code is written in the code-behind of, say, your `Sheet1` module, then `Range("B13")` is implicitly `Me.Range("B13")`.

If that code is written in some standard module, say, `Module1`, then `Range("B13")` is implicitly referring to *whatever worksheet happens to be currently active*. [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (free, open-source VBIDE add-in project that I manage) can locate every instance of such implicit `ActiveSheet` reference for you.

What you want, is to *never* use `Range`, `Columns`, `Rows`, `Names`, or `Cells`, without a proper, explicit `Worksheet` qualifier object.

So you declare and assign a `Worksheet` object:

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Some Sheet")

Dim destinationSheet As Workshet
Set destinationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Some Other Sheet")
```

And now you can get a `Range` from either sheet:

```
sourceSheet.Range("B13").Value = 42
destinationSheet.Range("A1").Value = sourceShet.Range("A1").Value
```

If both sheets exist at compile-time in `ThisWorkbook` (the host document that contains your VBA project), then you don't need to declare any variables, because VBA already declared them for you - simply locate your sheets in the VBE's *Project Explorer*, and set their `(Name)` property to any valid VBA identifier (no spaces, must start with a letter). ...and then you can just use these identifiers in your code as-is.

---

Watch out here:

> ```
> Range("U") & Rows.Count
> ```

That will throw error 1004, because `"U"` is not a valid cell reference (unless you have a *named range* that you conveniently named `U`, of course), and then the `& Rows.Count` is being concatenated to whatever `Range.[_Default]` happens to return for this `"U"` range (assuming it doesn't just blow up).

You likely meant to concatenate the number of rows with the column heading `U`, to get a `Range` off the concatenated cell address:

```
Range("U" & Rows.Count)
```